# Get list of domains for an Organization using Google Apps Admin SDK?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

An organization in Google Apps can have [multiple domains](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182452).

API requests to the Admin SDK require the domain name as a parameter. 
Ex:

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/{domainName}/general/defaultLanguage
```

Is there a way to programatically list all domains for an organization? If, for example, you wanted to change the lanaguage for all domains in an organization, there doesn't seem to be any way to list/iterate through the domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set separate policies or Admin Settings API per a domain when the domains are in the same Google Apps instance. See the [Google Limitations for multiple domains](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081) document.

To answer your first question, the Admin SDK does not have a method that allows the retrieval of all domains. However, you can [retrieve all users in the Google Apps instance](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users) and use that to determine what domains users have been created in.

Comment: Helpful answer, Jay. Not what I was hoping... but I'll file an enhancement request to get all domains through the Admin SDK.

Comment: Enhancement request: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3430

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of **Directory API**, Google added a functionality called **Domains** that let you get the domain list of a customer.

Check the below link

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/domains